# Samba Winbindd Failing Everyday

Tags: networking, samba, active-directory, samba4

Everyday morning on my domain controller running samba `4.7.6-ubuntu`  winbind fails, If I try to run the command `wbinfo -u` (to list all users) I get the error

```
could not obtain winbind interface details: WBC_ERR_WINBIND_NOT_AVAILABLE
could not obtain winbind domain name!
Error looking up domain users
```

As per a question in the comments

```
sudo systemctl status winbind.service
● winbind.service - Samba Winbind Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/winbind.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-10-21 15:51:08 BST; 1h 51min ago
     Docs: man:winbindd(8)
           man:samba(7)
           man:smb.conf(5)
  Process: 1249 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/winbindd --foreground --no-process-group $WINBINDOPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1249 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 21 15:51:07 pluto systemd[1]: Starting Samba Winbind Daemon...
Oct 21 15:51:08 pluto systemd[1]: winbind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 21 15:51:08 pluto systemd[1]: winbind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 21 15:51:08 pluto systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba Winbind Daemon.
```

Anybody else run into this issue ?

Comment: Could you post the result of `sudo systemctl status winbind.service`

Comment: See update to the question

Comment: You should check `/var/log/samba`, and also post your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file. And then try to join the domain one more time, and keep an eye on it. If this keeps happening, maybe  somehow your machine is losing the domain credentials stored on disk.

Comment: My problem was I purged Samba... So I purged winbind too. Everything related to W****ws makes me shivering.